# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n+\frac{1}{n})e^{\frac{1}{n}}-n$

Tags: limits

> Evaluation of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(n+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)e^{\frac{1}{n}}-n$$

What i try

Let $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}=x, $ Then $x\rightarrow 0$

So $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)e^{x}-\frac{1}{x}$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work it out after your pace. Since
 $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1\\\lim_{x\to0}xe^x=0$$
We deduce that,$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)e^{x}-\frac{1}{x}=1$$

Answer (score 4):

Option:

$e^{1/n}=1+1/n+O(1/n^2)$;

$(n+1/n)e^{1/n}-n=$

$(n+1+1/n+1/n^2+O(1/n))-n=$

$1+O(1/n)$;

Answer (score 3):

You can also do a squeezing because the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)  and the strict monotonicity of $e^x$ give

- $1+\frac 1n < e^{\frac 1n} < 1+\frac{e^{\frac 1n}}{n}$

Hence,

$$\left(n+\frac 1n\right)\left(1+\frac 1n\right) -n < \left(n+\frac 1n\right)e^{\frac 1n} -n < \left(n+\frac 1n\right)\left(1+\frac{e^{\frac 1n}}{n}\right) -n$$
$$\Leftrightarrow $$ 
$$\underbrace{1+\frac 1n + \frac 1{n^2}}_{\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1} < \left(n+\frac 1n\right)e^{\frac 1n} -n < \underbrace{e^{\frac 1n} + \frac 1n + \frac {e^{\frac 1n}}{n^2}}_{\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1}$$

Comment: Thanks Trancelocation  please explain me how i prove $e^{x}<1+xe^{x}$ for $x>0$

Comment: @jacky : 
The mean value theorem gives for $x > 0$

$$e^x-e^0 = e^{\xi}(x-0) \mbox{ with } 0 < \xi < x$$

Hence, using the strict monotonicity of $e^x$ you get

$$xe^0 < e^x-1 < xe^x$$ 
$$\Leftrightarrow 1+x < e^x < 1+xe^x$$

Comment: Thanks   trancelocation Got it.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing with you,

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(x^2+1)e^x-1}{x}=lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(2x)e^x+(x^2+1)e^x}{1}$ [Differentiating both numerator and denominator using L'Hospital rule,since it is a $\frac{0}{0}$ form.]

Now,it is clear that the limit$=(2*0)*e^0+(0^2+1)*e^0=1.$